# Disappearing comment in Android Studio - is it bug?

Tags: android, android-studio

I see something strange in Android Studio. When I write something like this:

```
/**
 * Some comment
 */
private int variable;
```

And click on "variable" with right mouse button->refactor->encapsulate fields->refactor
I got getters and setters and these lines in my code:

```
/**
 * Some comment
 */
```

...disappering.
Is it bug or I'm doing something wrong? (Or I don't understand something?)

EDIT. I see that in Eclipse comments don't disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Android Studio (0.4.0) moves Javadocs to getter but you can change it in a window "Encapsulate fields" (on the right side)

Comment: Thanks, I missed it. I just now found comments in the end of my program...:).